# Hapijs-react-views setup

Tags: node.js, reactjs, hapi.js

I'm finding some difficulties to follow the guide for hapijs-react-views package setup ([npm hapi-js-react-views](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapijs-react-views)).

I can run the server but I only get this error on localhost:3000

```
{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"}
```

My repo on github is: [hapi-react GitHub](https://github.com/MariaSales/hapireact)

My code is:

```
-routes
--index.js
-views
--index.jsx
-app.js
-package.js
```

// routes/index.js

```
exports.index = function(request, reply){
  reply.view('index', { name: 'John' });
};
```

// views/index.js

```
var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
   }
});

module.exports = HelloMessage;
```

//app.js

```
var hapi = require('hapi');
var vision = require('vision');
var path = require('path');
var engine = require('hapijs-react-views')();

// Create a server with a host and port
var server = new hapi.Server();
server.connection({ 
    host: 'localhost', 
    port: 3000 
});

// Register Hapi plugins
server.register(vision, function (err) {
  if(err) throw err;
});

var options = { jsx: { harmony: true } };
server.views({
    defaultExtension: 'jsx',
    engines: {
        jsx: require('hapijs-react-views')(options), // support for .jsx files
        js: require('hapijs-react-views')(options) // support for .js
    },
    relativeTo: __dirname,
    path: 'views'
});

// Add the route
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/',
    config: {
        handler: require('./routes').index
    }
});

// Start the server
server.start((err) => {

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Server running at:', server.info.uri);
});
```

//package.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "hapi": "^13.4.1",
    "hapijs-react-views": "^0.7.3",
    "react": "^15.1.0",
    "vision": "^4.1.0"
  }
```

Can you help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're getting an internal server error. Why is impossible to tell because you haven't provided enough code/info. It could be 1000 different reasons.

Comment: You can see all my code in the github repo. Do you prefer I paste it in here?

Comment: Yes please, code should be provided in posts whenever possible on SO. Don't post your whole project though, just the bits that you believe are relevant to your issue.

Comment: Ok thanks. I already added the code.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who sees this in the future, there's a working example of `jsx` rendering with `vision` here: https://github.com/hapijs/vision/tree/master/examples/jsx

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue. The documentation doesn't say but you still require React in your view files. That fixed the problem for me.